# Proving that $y$ is a square mod $p$ and $-y$ is square mod $q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given that $p, q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, neither $y$ nor $-y$ has a square root mod $pq$, and that $y$ is invertible mod $pq$, how would I prove that $y$ is a square mod one of $p, q$ and $-y$ is a square mod the other?

Comment: Key fact: For any prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$, and any $y$ not divisible by $p$, **exactly one** of $y$ or $-y$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

Comment: Is this a theorem that I can look up?

Comment: I don't know, some books may point it out, some may not.  Let us prove it using a Legendre symbol calculation. We have $(-y/p)=(-1/p)(y/p)=-(y/p)$ since $(-1/p)=-1$ ($-1$ is not a QR of any prime of the form $4k+3$).

Comment: What's the line of reasoning to show that y is not divisible by p?

Comment: We are told $y$ is invertible mod $pq$, so $y$ is divisible by neither $p$ nor $q$.

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question does not state explicitly that $p$ and $q$ are prime, the notation suggests that they are. Also, the claimed result need not hold if $p$ and $q$ are not prime. So we assume that $p$ and $q$ sre prime.

The number $y$ is invertible modulo $pq$, so neither $p$ nor $q$ divides $y$. First we show that *exactly one* of $y$ and $-y$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, and exactly one of $y$ and $-y$ is a quadratic residue of $q$.

To prove this, we use a Legendre symbol calculation. We have 
$$(-y/p)=(-1/p)(y/p)=-(y/p).$$ (We have $(-1/p)=-1$ because $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.) The same argument works for $q$.

We are told that neither $y$ nor $-y$ is a square modulo $pq$. Suppose first that $y$ is a square modulo $p$. Then $y$ cannot be a square modulo $q$, else $y$ would be a square modulo both $p$ and $q$, and therefore (Chinese Remainder Theorem) modulo $pq$.

Thus if $y$ is a square modulo $p$, then $-y$ is a square modulo $q$.

Similarly, if $y$ is not a square modulo $p$, then $-y$ is a square modulo $p$. If $-y$ were a square modulo $q$, then $-y$ would be a square modulo $pq$, contradicting the given fact that it is not. So $y$ is a square modulo $q$. This completes the proof.